# Masked Edit Extender: custom mask for e-mail textbox, is there any way to restrict the user to a specific domain with a custom mask?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, maskedtextbox

I have a register page for the user, but it should only allow the user to enter one specific domain for their email, like this:

```
*@example.com
```

The username for the email can be anything, but the domain **must** be pre-typed and cannot change. I'm trying to do it with Ajax Masked Edit Extender but I can't find a way to make the domain a static value like I want.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" Mask="AAAAAA@domain.com"
        InputDirection="LeftToRight" TargetControlID="txtemail">
    </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

In mask property `in place of AAAAAA` you want add more `AAA` it's depend on your requiredment how much `character` to allow user to enterde.

OR

you have put like this option in textbox user can enter only `character` whatever you pass in mask property.

Like Below Image:

[image: Mask]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.90).aspx[MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to do it in your controller or code-behind file ?

if not.. you'll need to handle it with javaScript