# Email mask for MaskedTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, maskedtextbox

Does anyone have a ready email mask for MaskedTextBox?

e.g.

```
aaaa...aaa@fff.ee / aaaa...aaa@ff.ee / aaaa...aaa@fff.eee / aaaa...aaa@ff.eee /
```

p.s. Please do not suggest RegEx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try {
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put source that where you get this answer

Comment: This works for '@', but it does not check if '.' is necessary after. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Mike you can get more information at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" Mask="AAAAAA@domain.com"
        InputDirection="LeftToRight" TargetControlID="txtemail">
    </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

In mask property `in place of AAAAAA` you want add more `AAA` it's depend on your requiredment how much `character` to allow user to enterde.

OR

you have put like this option in textbox user can enter only `character` whatever you pass in mask property.

Like Below Image:

[image: Mask]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.90).aspx[MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253518/masked-edit-extender-custom-mask-for-e-mail-textbox-is-there-anyway-to-restric)

Comment: Nice one, but what if I want to allow random domain and extension?

Answer (score 0):

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format

```
    public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
    {
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
             return false;

        try
        {
            // Normalize the domain
            email = Regex.Replace(email, @"(@)(.+)$", DomainMapper,
                                      RegexOptions.None,     TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

            // Examines the domain part of the email and normalizes it.
            string DomainMapper(Match match)
            {
                // Use IdnMapping class to convert Unicode domain names.
                var idn = new IdnMapping();

                // Pull out and process domain name (throws ArgumentException on     invalid)
                    string domainName = idn.GetAscii(match.Groups[2].Value);

                return match.Groups[1].Value + domainName;
            }
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(email,@"^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+$",     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```